# How to yank in a search in an emacs lisp function

Tags: function, search, emacs, lisp, yank

```
(defun search-for-what-is-just-killed () 
(interactive)
(search-forward latestkillringvariable? nil t)
)
```

How to use "yank" in an emacs lisp function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access directly the `kill-ring` list to access the latest kill:

```
 (substring-no-properties (car kill-ring))
```

The `substring-no-properties` bit is important since text is kept in the kill ring with additional properties (like fontification specific to a particular mode and you'll probably want to strip those).

Comment: Excellent. Does what it has to. I am guessing that "car" calls kill-ring as a list, how does it know that it needs the first item?

Comment: `car` is a function that retrieves the first element of a list (`kill-ring` is a list)